# Nginx перенаправляет на неправильный домен (Nginx+uwsgi+Django)

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, uwsgi

Приветствую всех!

Настраиваю сервер с **двумя** доменами. (Предположим: "test.com", "test2.com")
При переходе на test2.com, выскакивает ошибка 400 (Bad request).
Если зайти по айпи test2.com, то уже перенаправляет до test.com...
Самое интересное, что этот 400 Bad request фиксируется в логах uwsgi сайта "test.com". Оба сайта используют перенаправление с http до https.

Вопрос: Почему он (или не он) перенаправляет до "test.com" нежели до "test2.com"? Если настройки Nginx будут нужны, могу их приложить.

Конфигурация "test2.com"

```
# test2.com

upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/test2.sock;  
}

server {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test2.com, www.test2.com;
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
    }

}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    listen   [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name test2.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    client_max_body_size 75M;  

    error_page 502 /502.html;

    location = /502.html {

    root  /home/User/html;

    }

    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/django/test2/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/django/test2/static;

    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/django/test2/uwsgi_params; 
    }


}
```

Конфигурация "test.com":

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/test.sock;  
}

# конфигурация веб-сервера
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    # доменное имя
    server_name test.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;  

    error_page 502 /502.html;

    location = /502.html {

    root  /home/User/html;

    }

    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/djangoc/test/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/djangoc/test/static;

    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/djangoc/test/uwsgi_params; 
    }

}
```

UWSGI конфигурация к серверу "test2.com":
    [uwsgi]

```
plugin=python3
chdir           = /var/www/django/test2
module          = test2.wsgi
home            = /var/www/django/venv

master          = true
socket          = /tmp/test2.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
pidfile2 = /tmp/test2-master.pid
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/test2.log
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/test2.log
py-autoreload=5
```

Comment: Ничего не понял, без настроек видимо не обойтись. В логах nginx есть что-нибудь интересное?

Comment: Ничего интересного там нет. Сейчас приложу конфиг...

Comment: эти домены обслуживает один и тот же экземпляр программы nginx?

Comment: Простите, я не очень понимаю что вы имеете в виду... но если вы про то, запущен ли процесс Nginx один раз, то да.

Comment: Какие-то мутные настройки. Если у вас действительно один Nginx, то `sudo nginx -t` должен очень сильно ругаться на их неправильность, например на повторение одного и того же `upstream django` два раза

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` возвращает что все чисто, конфиг примерный приведен. Большинство самых нужных данных в конфиге, а `сертификат\upstream` и т.д. в оригинале присутствуют.

Comment: Нет-нет, давайте не примерный, иначе я заявлю, что проблема в неправильном upstream :)

Comment: Так это и есть оригинальный конфиг, изменены название домена и названия upstream (С djangoserver1 djangoserver 2 на django) + убран сертификат. Больше ничего не убрано.

Comment: Вы всё лишь излишне запутываете, но ладно, каков конфиг uwsgi?

Comment: Сейчас прикреплю.

Comment: если это конфигурация одного сервера, то, как минимум, идентификаторы должны быть уникальными: у вас два разных описания для одной и той же (с именем `django`) секции `upstream`. ну и `/tmp/test.sock` никто не слушает, если судить по приведённой вами информации. p.s. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply